# Synonyms of Residual Sum of Squares

Tags: terminology, sums-of-squares

As a novice, I'm finding it difficult to learn statistics, partly because there are often many different words for the same thing. When I'm reading about stats, I don't realize that the thing I'm reading about (A) is actually the same thing that I read about yesterday (B).

So I thought I'd ask a question about synonyms, for my own benefit, and for other novices who might be in the same boat:

---

What are the various synonyms for **Residual Sum of Squares** (RSS)?

Answer (score 0):

These are the synonyms I've come across so far:

1. Residual Sum of Squares (RSS)
2. Sum of Squared Deviations (SSD)
3. Sum of Squared Residuals (SSR)
4. Sum of Squared Estimate of Errors (SSE)